# What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $AX=B$ to be solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be real $3\times3$ matrices. What are necessary and sufficient conditions on A for there to exist a unique real $3\times3$ matrix $X$ satisfying $AX=B$?

"$A$ is invertible" is clearly a sufficient condition, since we can then multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ to get $X=A^{-1}B$.

If $A$ is singular, can there still be a unique solution $X$? In that case, what would the necessary condition be?

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, then rank$(A)<3$. In which case kernel is non-trivial, hence uniqueness is gone.

Comment: Think of those matrices as linear maps. You can see that when you post-multiply a vector by $A$ then if it lies in the kernel of $A$ nothing can rescue it giving some freedom of choice for $X$.

Comment: To expand on Anurag A's comment, let $k$ be a nonzero vector in the kernel of $A$, and define $K$ to be the $3\times 3$ matrix with each column equal to $k$. Then if $X_0$ is some solution, $A(X_0+tK)=AX_0+tAK=B$, so solutions cannot be unique.

Comment: we might want to have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem